# Generate colorful streamline pattern (using FOSS)

Tags: inkscape, gimp, patterns, palette, python

I found a very interesting pattern, which I would like to recreate:

[image: pattern image]
[Source](https://solecollector.com/news/2015/04/converse-weapon-20)

I tried to start with the RGB-Noise filter of Gimp, but didn't get a comparable pattern so far. I understood, that there are 2 challenges:
Generating the pattern itself and generating the palette.

Preferably, I would like to use FOS-software like Inkscape, Gimp, maybe even Python, since it's available.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is for GIMP

1. Start with something like an A5 canvas size
2. Create a new brush like this

[image]

3. Create a new Paint Dynamic preset, and set the matrix as follows

[image]

4. Increase the size of the brush as you like, and paint random coloured lines, choosing different colours, on a new transparent layer above a black background layer.
5. Continue until you've built up enough coloured lines on the new layer.  You only need a small section, it doesn't have to cover the entire canvas.

[image]

6. Click *Edit > Preferences > Tool Options*, and for the Scaling option set the Default interpolation  to "None"
7. Back in your document hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to bring up the transform handles and stretch the image something like this. When you have finished, hit the New Layer icon in the layers panel to add the new stretched layer to a layer of its own.

[image]

8. Now duplicate the resulting Transformation layer, and reposition with the move tool. Repeat until you have covered the entire canvas.

[image]

Just a little note to add. You could do this on a much smaller scale and use the Pencil instead of the brush tool, so that you get perfect pixel wide stripes. Then scale the whole thing up with interpolation set to none.  Then add [a texture](https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2421/3662741993_f58563f756_b.jpg) layer, desaturate it, and set the blending mode to hard light.

Here's the result of doing that.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Photoshop is not in the list, but just in case.
Image from [unsplash.com](https://unsplash.com/photos/bC3Q_8VJGzs):

[image: photo]

Menu Filter > Noise > Add noise

[image: noise]

Menu Filter > Blur > Motion Blur

[image: blur II]

Menu Filter > Sharpen > Smart sharpen

[image: sharp]

Select the part of the image you like most and crop it.

Adding an **Adjustment layer** of **Hue/Saturation** choose the color style:

[image: gif]

Rotate 90º

[image: rotate]

To increase the image size if it's necessary, resample with Nearest Neighbor:

[image: resample]

Change the Adjustment Layer to **Vivid Light**:

[image: vivid]

Comment: That gif is mesmerizing!

Comment: Nice answer. It looks like that approach might also work in GIMP. It has a motion blur effect, rgb noise, sharpening filter, and hue-saturation adjustment.

Comment: Photoshop is not FOSS

Answer (score 14):

Here' my approach for Gimp:

1. Used an interesting photo with colours I liked

   [image]
   Source: [Wikimedia - New York Times Square](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:New_york_times_square-terabass.jpg)
2. Chose a region of interest from this photo

   [image]
3. Increased saturation, contrast, and (optionally) made an indexed Image

   [image]
4. Used the inbuilt filter [paper tile](https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-papertile.html) with broad width and low height

   [image]
5. Scaled image to desired width

   [image]

The fun part is when only you know the source photo hidden in the Image.

[image]

Comment: I’m pretty sure that’s Trump